# Retorno de uma Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, yii2

Tenho uma ação X na minha aplicação que ao realizá-la, é acionada uma *stored procedure* no banco que gera um `insert` em uma tabela. Até aqui tranquilo.

O que estou precisando é uma forma de que quando essa *stored procedure* for executada me retorne o que foi executado e se deu erro ou não.

Ex: tenho 5 ações, ao executá-las preciso de um retorno informando o que deu certo e o que deu erro para ser mostrado em uma grid para o Usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o try-catch dentro da sp:

```
BEGIN TRY  
    SELECT 1/0;  
END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH  
SELECT  
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
END CATCH;
```

Caso queira forçar um erro dependendo da lógica da sp, utilize o [RAISERROR](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Se você estiver utilizando uma versão mais antiga do SQL Server, você pode abrir uma transaction e dar commit ou rollback de acordo com uma condição ou erro.

```
DECLARE @E INT
BEGIN TRAN  
    SELECT 1/0;  

    SET @E = @@ERROR

    SELECT @E

IF @E > 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN
ELSE
    COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Não consigo avaliar. A sua resposta foi exatamenteo que eu estava precisando. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.